# How to replace a string empty by with help substring

Tags: c#, .net, replace

```
{adsafi**ClRf**udsaf**ClRf**adsf....EOF**ClRf** }
```

from the above string how to replace string.empty between EOF and }

output:

```
{adsafi**ClRf**udsaf**ClRf**adsf....EOF }**
```

Comment: in the above string more than one clrf was present. i cant reach my output.atleast i need after substring EOF every thing as empty

Comment: when you say String.Empty, do you mean Carriage Return/Line Feed? Sorry, i'm having trouble what you mean by Replacing nothing (String.Empty)

Comment: What do you want to happen if "EOF" appears multiple times in your string?

Comment: How do you imagine to find an empty string in a string? Is it string or byte array?

Comment: Have you looked at using `string.LastIndexOf` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
int lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf("something");
string result = input.Substring(lastIndex);
// or
string result = input.Substring(lastIndex, length);
```